# How pressure and velocity is related? And its effect in cavitation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, bernoulli-equation

I am confused as to why cavitation happens at end of turbine blade. As I understand it, when velocity increases and discharge is constant, the fluid (liquid) molecules get away from each other in the region where velocity is high and that's why they get converted into vapor.
Am I correct?

Comment: What kind of turbine?  If a steam turbine, there shouldn't be any cavitation.

Comment: Francis turbine

Answer (score 2):

Cavitation occurs when the flowing liquid's pressure drops below the vapor pressure of that liquid (in this case, water).  This happens inside pump and turbine cases when the liquid gets "squeezed" through a reduced cross-sectional area, the velocity increases, and the pressure decreases per the Bernoulli equation.

At the point where the cavitation occurs, very small steam bubbles form.  These bubbles typically don't last very long, as they soon encounter a higher pressure fluid region where fluid velocities decrease.  When this happens, the bubble collapses violently.  If the cavitation bubble collapses on metal surfaces, it will chip away a very small piece of metal and erode the metal in that spot.  Continued operation of pumps and turbines in a cavitating condition will destroy equipment.

There are several things to think about in order to either avoid cavitation, or engineer a solution where the cavitation is not destructive.

- If velocities in the turbine can be decreased, the maximum pressure drop inside the turbine will be reduced, and cavitation will be avoided.  Obviously, for a Francis turbine, this may not be possible, but if it is, it will result in a reduction in power produced
- If you can increase the upstream pressure on the Francis turbine and keep the water flow through the turbine constant, the pressure throughout the turbine should increase, hopefully to the point where cavitation is eliminated
- If there is a way to introduce water into the Francis turbine that has a lower temperature, cavitation can be eliminated by lowering the vapor pressure of the water to a point that is lower than the lowest pressure that the water experiences as it goes through the turbine
- In some cases, the water flow path can be redirected such that the lowest pressures are encountered inside the water stream.  When this happens, cavitation still occurs, but the collapsing vapor bubbles never touch a metal surface, which eliminates equipment damage
- It may be possible to apply a thin coating of a material that has "rubber like" properties.  Such a surface would tend to rebound when a cavitation bubble strikes it, rather than "flake off" like a metal does

As a start for investigating cavitation in Francis turbines, see https://caeai.com/resources/analysis-cavitation-inside-francis-turbine.

For a better idea of when cavitation occurs, consult the Antoine equation.  This equation calculates the vapor pressure of water at any given temperature, and it will tell you the minimum pressure that the Francis turbine can operate at and still avoid cavitation.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine_equation

In addition to the above, assuming that your Francis turbine is experiencing turbine blade erosion, you will want to get with the manufacturer and let him know what is happening.  Your cavitation problem is undoubtedly not unique, and there are probably solutions to this problem that have already been successfully implemented.

Comment: Thank you for the answer,still I am not satisfied.I want the relation between velocity and pressure at molecular level.  My question is what happened at cavitation point how increase in velocity decreases pressure at molecular level.Is at higher velocity water get stretched and molecules get detached and become vapor??

Comment: The molecules don't get "detached" or "stretched".  The liquid boils when the pressure goes below the vapor pressure.  Are you familiar with the Bernoulli equation?

Comment: I am getting what you meant sir,but I want to know how pressure get affected as velocity increases,how inside a liquid as velocity increases pressure decreases.what is behind this?

Comment: And if talking about Bernoulli's equation,this question arises from Bernoulli's equation,I understood Bernoulli's but can't feel it that how pressure and velocity are related what happened when velocity increases pressure comes down.Same is happening in Venturi meter cavitation occurs at throat what happened at throat how increase in velocity cause decease in  pressure,please explain not mathematically or by Bernoulli's principle.

Comment: Pressure is energy per unit volume.  The Bernoulli equation accounts for fluid pressure, fluid gravitational potential energy per unit volume, and fluid kinetic energy per unit volume, and it accounts for changes in those variables.  This means that the Bernoulli equation involves conservation of energy per unit volume of liquid.  As one of the variables in the Bernoulli equation changes, other variables change as well in order to conserve fluid energy.  For a constant fluid height, as fluid velocity increases, fluid pressure must decrease.

Comment: Thank you sir,you mean pressure energy is potential energy between the molecules of liquid as pressure decreases the molecules expands or get away from each other??

Comment: @RaviPandey, you're dealing with an incompressible fluid in this case.  The liquid does not "expand" as pressure decreases.  However, note that localized boiling occurs in the fluid, just as boiling always occurs.  When the local pressure falls below the vapor pressure of the liquid, the liquid begins boiling.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Bernoulli's principle of fluid flow, the pressure experienced by a moving fluid is inversely proportional to it's velocity. What causes that isn't clear, but from my standpoint I think the fluid being being stretched out over more length might have something to do with why there's pressure drop.

Comment: conservation of energy causes a decrease in pressure when velocity increases.

Comment: Is there a mathematical expression for that?

Comment: @TechDroid The most basic example is Bernoulli's principle; but that's really just energy conservation over different flow conditions.

Comment: TechDroid, the terms in the Bernoulli equation are all equivalent to pressure, and pressure is equivalent to energy per unit volume.  Look at the term $1/2 \rho v^2$.  This is CLEARLY kinetic energy per unit volume.  Thus, the Bernoulli equation represents energy conservation.

Comment: I get it. So let help the guy deal with his cavitation problem shall we.

Comment: So how cavitation takes place ...is it because the water molecules get stretched such that the bond get break and water molecules are converted into vapor.In other words its static pressure becomes lower that vapor pressure. Please suggest information regarding how pressure drop when vel of fluid increases.

Comment: The pressure is inversely *related* to velocity, but isn't inversely *proportional* to velocity. If it were, zero velocity fluids would have infinite pressure. And answers are for communicating established physics knowledge, not speculation.

Answer (score 0):

Pressure and velocity are related in a flowing fluid through the mechanical energy (Bernoulli) equation.  With no work on the fluid, as the velocity increases the pressure decreases. Other answers have addressed cavitation for a turbine.  Cavitation is also of concern for a pump. For a pump, the liquid pressure decreases from the pump intake to the volute, before the impeller does work and increases the pressure of the liquid.  If the pressure in the volute decreases to the saturation pressure at the temperature of the liquid, the fluid flashes; that is, vapor bubbles form. Once the impeller subsequently increases the pressure these bubbles collapse and send shock waves that can destroy the pump.  To prevent cavitation, the Net Positive Suction Head Available, NPSHA, (determined by the system) must exceed the Net Positive Suction Head Required, NPSHR, (a property of the pump). NPSHA is how much the pressure head is above the saturation pressure at the pump inlet; NPSHR is how much the pressure head at the pump inlet must be above the saturation pressure for the pressure to not be reduced to the saturation pressure as pressure is decreased when the fluid flows from the pump inlet into the pump volute.